# How to run T-SQL query on Ansible

Tags: ansible

My yaml:

```
- name: "Ensure 'Maximum number of error log files' is set to greater than or equal to '12'"
  win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -Query \"DECLARE @NumErrorLogs int; EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'NumErrorLogs', @NumErrorLogs OUTPUT; SELECT ISNULL(@NumErrorLogs, -1) AS [NumberOfLogFiles];\" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | ConvertTo-Json"
  register: response

- set_fact:
    ids: "{{ response.stdout}}"

- debug:
    var: ids
```

Error response:

```
- name: "Ensure 'Maximum number of error log files' is set to greater than or equal to '12'"
  win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -Query \"DECLARE @NumErrorLogs int; EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'NumErrorLogs', @NumErrorLogs OUTPUT; SELECT ISNULL(@NumErrorLogs, -1) AS [NumberOfLogFiles];\" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | ConvertTo-Json"
                                                                                                                                     ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes.

Comment: Ansible is trying to interpret the char `\M`, simply escape the `\\` by doubling them.

Comment: Thanks @zigarn
Solved!

TASK [Ensure 'Maximum number of error log files' is set to greater than or equal to '12'] ***
changed: [104.215.183.33]
TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [104.215.183.33]
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [104.215.183.33] => {
    "ids": {
        "NumberOfLogFiles": -1
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible is trying to interpret the char `\M`, simply escape the `\` by doubling them `\\`:

```yaml
- name: "Ensure 'Maximum number of error log files' is set to greater than or equal to '12'"
  win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -Query \"DECLARE @NumErrorLogs int; EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\\Microsoft\\MSSQLServer\\MSSQLServer', N'NumErrorLogs', @NumErrorLogs OUTPUT; SELECT ISNULL(@NumErrorLogs, -1) AS [NumberOfLogFiles];\" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | ConvertTo-Json"
  register: response
```